No puedo pasar el valor de una variable del server al cliente
el prop que paso es {defaultOpen} que mira que accordion debe permanecer abierto en este caso le puedo asignar un numero manual segun la posicion en el array por ejemplo [0] para que quede abierto el primero eso es el caso basico pero si por ejemplo al entrar al aparto del accordion que muestra productos vienen por un enlace que dice que accordion tiene que permacener abierto: 'http://localhost:4321/productos?categoria=2' entonces el valor tien que cambiar a [2] segun yo me falta mas logica ya que si logro extraer la url con window.location.href o con astro URL pero en este caso del lado del cliente no me permite astro manipular el dom segun el server, y al utilizar window.location.href es lo mismo pero si lo hago desde el server con un script, ya luego no puedo pasar ese valor del lado del cliente, este es mi codigo.
    ---
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";  
import Accordion from "./Accordion";
import productos from "../../data/productos.json";
import Formulario from "../Main/Formulario.astro";
import Mapa from "../Main/Mapa.astro";

// Agrupar productos por categoría
// Suponiendo que productos es tu lista importada de productos.json
const categoriasAgrupadas = productos.reduce((acc, producto) => {
  // Si la categoría ya existe, añade el producto a ella; si no, crea una nueva categoría
  if (!acc[producto.categoria]) {
    acc[producto.categoria] = {
      title: producto.categoria,
      products: [],
    };
  }
  acc[producto.categoria].products.push(producto);
  return acc;
}, {});

// Convertir el objeto en un array de categorías
const categorias = Object.values(categoriasAgrupadas);


---
<script>
  // Este script ya está correctamente colocado para ejecutarse solo en el cliente
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const getCategoriaFromUrl = () => {
      const url = new URL(window.location.href);
      console.log(window.location.href);
      const params = url.searchParams;
      const categoria = params.get('categoria');
      return categoria ? parseInt(categoria, 10) : 0;
    };

    const defaultOpenValue = getCategoriaFromUrl();
    console.log('defaultOpen:', defaultOpenValue);
    
  });
</script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Menú Acordeón</title>
  </head>
  <body class="">
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="accordion-root" class="">
      <Accordion categories={categorias} defaultOpen={defaultOpen} client:visible />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-20 max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <Formulario />
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-7xl m-auto">
    <Mapa />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


Para manejar estados con la URL suelo usar react router, hay un hook llamado useLocation() + la clase URLSearchParams, que te permite hacerlo en el cliente.
Si deseas saber mas información, mira la documentación de react router v6, la cual es la mas moderna a la fecha

Esta información debe ser agregada como un comentario a la pregunta, no se puede considerar una respuesta
